# What happens to a time sphere if no one chooses to use it?

Tags: futurama

In the episode *[Bender's Big Score](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender%27s_big_score)* a time sphere is summoned and Nibbler warns that a single use could tear the universe asunder. What would happen to the time sphere itself if Nibbler's warning was heeded and the time sphere was never used?

Would it simply disappear after a certain time had passed? In which case, would it still disappear if someone was inside it (but chose to never use it for the remainder of their life)?

Or perhaps the time sphere would stick around indefinitely, in which case how would civilization / government avoid its use (i.e. transport it to a secure location (can it  be moved?), implode it, or otherwise seal it off)?

Comment: Excellent question, but purely speculative unless they addressed it *in-universe* later on.

Comment: The time sphere is inherently linked to the timeline of the universe, which involves the sphere being used.  If the usage of the sphere was not part of the universal timeline, the sphere could never have existed.  In other words, if the sphere weren't used, it wouldn't have made it into the writing of the episode.  This is Futurama, not Isaac Asimov.